# Expo push notification behavior

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

I'm new in react-native development. I try to set notifications with expo-notification on my app. I receive notifications on Ios & Android. When my app is already open via the expo qr code, the notification redirect the user to the right screen on my app. But when my app is not open, the notification opens the expo app instead of mine. Is it the expected behavior?